# convert Text area into pdf file

Tags: java, pdf

how I can get a field (text area) from my database and read it as a pdf

Comment: what have you tried yourself, add some code. Hi and welcome to SO. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean, to retrieve a text value and read it as pdf?

If you read values from a database at the most you can use these values to generate a pdf through a library like PDFBox, IText or [GlobalReports](http://www.globalreports.it/en/)